# Do I need to call malloc() for other field in a struct after calling malloc for that struct itself?

Tags: c

Let say I have a type node_t

```
typedef struct node{
    char* value;
    struct node *next;
}node_t;
```

When I want to create a new node_t pointer named n1, I call malloc

```
node_t *n1 = malloc(sizeof(node_t));
```

Now I want to access and use other fields inside n1 : value and next, do I have to call malloc for these pointer again, like this:

```
n1->value = malloc(sizeof(char));
n1->next = malloc(sizeof(node_t));
```

Or the very first calling malloc() when creating n1 have already do all these thing ?

Comment: `malloc` allocates a new `node_t`, and nothing more. It does not initialize the members of the allocated `struct`, and it certainly does not allocate memory for any pointers that are members of the `struct`.

Comment: `sizeof(char)` is _always_ 1 [by definition]. So, don't use it. So, generally, you'd want (e.g.) `char str[] = "A string to store"; n1->value = strdup(str);` And, again, when recreating a given node (e.g.) `n1` you don't create the `next` node at the same time. That comes later [usually, in a subsequent call to the create function]

Answer (score 2):

> do I have to call malloc for these pointer again

It depends on how you want to use those members.

When you malloc a `node_t` you get memory for storing 1) a `char` pointer and 2) a `node_t` pointer. You can set these pointers to point to other existing objects. But you can also set these pointers to point to new (dynamic allocated) objects.

**Example 1**

```
node_t *n1 = malloc(sizeof *n1);
assert(n1 != NULL);
n1->value = "Hello world";
n1->next = NULL;

node_t *n2 = malloc(sizeof *n2);
assert(n2 != NULL);
n2->value = "Have fun";
n2->next = NULL;

n1->next = n2;  // Create a linked list
```

In this example there is no direct malloc for any members of `node_t`. The members are just set to point to other objects.

**Example 2**

```
node_t *n1 = malloc(sizeof *n1);
assert(n1 != NULL);
n1->value = "Hello world";

n1->next = malloc(sizeof *n1->next);
assert(n1->next != NULL);
n1->next->value = "Have fun";
n1->next->next = NULL;
```

This example results in the same as the first example. It's just written a little different, i.e. the `next` pointer of `n1` is assigned to point to a new malloc'ed `node_t` instead of having a `n2` object.

**Example 3**

```
char *str1= "Hello world";
char *str2= "Have fun";

node_t *n1 = malloc(sizeof *n1);
assert(n1 != NULL);
n1->value = malloc(1 + strlen(str1));
strcpy(n1->value, str1);  // Copy the string

n1->next = malloc(sizeof *n1->next);
assert(n1->next != NULL);
n1->next->value = malloc(1 + strlen(str2));
strcpy(n1->next->value, str2);  // Copy the string
n1->next->next = NULL;
```

Here the `value` pointer is set to point to a new malloc'ed object and a **copy** of a string is placed in that object.

So - to repeat - whether you want to malloc memory for the members depends on how you want to use the struct.

Comment: Don't use `assert` to check the return value of `malloc`. `assert` is meant to be used for checking for programming errors during debugging, and not for runtime errors. It is perfectly OK for a c-implementation to define `assert` as a no-op.